# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'password')

Tags: node.js, mongodb, passwords, bcrypt

1. I am receiving error in the line:
   `bcrypt.hash(req.body.password,10,function(err,hashedPass)`
2. Please help me to figure it out.

```js
//controller section

const User =require('../Model/User');
const bcrypt=require('bcryptjs');
const jwt=require('jsonwebtoken');

const register =(req,res,next)=>{bcrypt.hash(req.body.password,10,function(err,hashedPass){
        if(err){
            res.json({
                error:err
            })
        }let user= new User({
            firstname:req.body.firstname,
            lastname:req.body.lastname,
            email:req.body.email,
            password:hashedPass
        })
       user.save()
        .then(user=>{
            res.json({
                message:"User Added Successfully"
            })
        }).catch(error=>{
            res.json({message:'An error Ocurred'});})
    })   
}
module.exports={register}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is due to the password not being defined in the request body. So the execution of `req.body.password` in the `bcrypt.hash` function will throw the error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'password')`.

Make sure while sending the HTTP request you're specifying the password in the request body.

Comment: I had put the require('body-parser') below to the router(user router) in app.js, tat was the reason it could not find...now updated correctly and working fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This error suggests that JSON data is not parsed from the request body.
You could use a parsing middleware such as bodyparser (https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) or express.json.

For body parser, add this block to your code:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

For express.json, add this line to your code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
```